# How can you change the Business Unit of a user in CRM programmatically?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I've done the following, which throws no errors but doesn't update my users Business Unit:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
query.EntityName = "systemuser";
query.ColumnSet = new AllColumns();

ConditionExpression ce = new ConditionExpression();
ce.AttributeName = "businessunitid";
ce.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
ce.Values = new string[] { My BU Guid };

ConditionExpression ce2 = new ConditionExpression();
ce2.AttributeName = "lastname";
ce2.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
ce2.Values = new string[] { Users Lastname };

FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
filter.Conditions = new ConditionExpression[] { ce, ce2 };
query.Criteria = filter;

try
{
    BusinessEntityCollection UserCollection = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    foreach (BusinessEntity be in UserCollection.BusinessEntities)
    {
        //Update users BU. Roles will need to be added back in.
        Guid newBu = new Guid(New BU Guid);
        systemuser su = (systemuser)be;
        su.businessunitid.Value = newBu;
        TargetUpdateSystemUser sysuserUpdate = new TargetUpdateSystemUser() { SystemUser = su };
        UpdateRequest userBUUpdate = new UpdateRequest() { Target = sysuserUpdate };
        crmService.Execute(userBUUpdate);
    }
catch
{
}
```

At the moment this returns 1 user and throws no errors. However, on checking the user in CRM their BU hasn't changed. I've also tried simply crmService.Update(su) but that doesn't work either. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't update the business unit as other standard fields.

You need to use a `SetBusinessSystemUserRequest`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb929627.aspx

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want but I don't fully understand the ReassignPrincipal property. Have you got any examples you could point me to?

Comment: I found this: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4398e02-d638-4ce2-827e-dd2b6dc698af/setting-users-business-unit-programmatically?forum=crmdevelopment but there's no explanation as to what the Security Principal is.

Comment: You must specify a value for the ReassignPrincipal property. The instances of the entities that had been assigned to the user specified by the UserId property will be assigned to that security principal (user). When a user moves to another business unit the records he owns may need to be assigned to a collegue in his old business unit. Otherwise, his collegues may no longer have access to these records.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen - thanks for that. I suspected that after some further research. However, for the purpose of what I'm doing I can just move everything with the user.